# How to hyper link this URL in SVG?

Tags: svg

I have following url which has & in between url so its not working fine how to get solution for this

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

    <a xlink:href="http://192.168.11.235:8086/web?#id=4**&**view_type=form**&**model=asset.asset&menu_id=208&action=233" target="_top">
        <rect x="10" y="20" width="75" height="30"
                style="stroke: #333366; fill: #6666cc"/>
    </a>

</svg>
```

Because of &(and ) symbol I am getting error how to resolve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <a xlink:href="http://192.168.11.235:8086/web?#id=4&amp;view_type=form&amp;model=asset.asset&amp;menu_id=208&action=233" target="_top">
```

This will work properly thanks for giving me hint

Answer (score 0):

What about you encode your special url code : & = %26

```
%26
```

for more url encodes:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: after clicking on that url the path is not converting in to & insted of this its displayin %26 please add my url encode here please